# What are my obligations if I bundle rasterized CC BY 4.0-licensed vector icons in my software?

Tags: derivative-works, cc-by

I'm considering using the free version of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com) in my closed-source game. Its icons are licensed under CC BY 4.0. Because of how the game engine works, the game would embed rasterized versions of the SVG files, *not* the original vector icons. **Given this, what would my obligations be when using Font Awesome in this way?**

Comment: Well CC-BY really only has one requirement: Attribution, and you aren't absolved from that by changing just the data format.

Comment: That's it? It's not more complicated than that?

Comment: What obligation do you see in the license that you think you might have?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked. I figured that because I'm not redistributing the SVGs it would make things more complicated.

Comment: The main question in my mind is whether you need to notify that you modified the images. Is casting to a raster a format change or a derivative work? Either way, you can certainly do it.

Comment: In my case I'm also changing the color to white (from the default black) so it's probably a derivative work.

Comment: As soon as you use a work and change anything in it (format, colour, whatever), it's a derivative. Then just do what the license of the original asks you. In case of CC-BY: give credits (and no, 'wikipedia' as one sometimes sees is not giving credits. However Wikipedia has good guides / recommendations on how to credit its media if you need examples)